# Full CPU usage but no command in htop

Tags: htop

Ubuntu server is running at 100% cpu when booting. Htop is not showing any process above 2-3% usage. Is there any way to investigate which processes using the cpu?
[Htop usage in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vtnZ.png)

Comment: `htop` may miss commands if they executed and finish too quickly, such as when I'm compiling C++ applications. You can quit and restart `htop` and look immediately when the output shows up, or you can try `systemd-cgtop` to see which cgroup has processes that using the most CPU